# Invalid SQL data type error when deleting row from database?

Tags: html, sql, jsp, jdbc

I'm trying to delete a row from my MS Access database using JSP files. But i'm getting the following error below. Anyone know how to fix it. Thanks. Any help would be much appreciated.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:    DELETE FROM Employees WHERE empId =
>   ?    : [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   DELETE FROM Employees WHERE empId = ?

---

### Code: JSP File.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>DELETE Operation</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource
    var = "bookdB"
    scope = "session"
    driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
    url = "jdbc:odbc:bookdB"
/>

<c:set var="empId" value="${param['empId']}"/>

<sql:update dataSource="${bookdB}" var="count">
  DELETE FROM Employees WHERE empId = ?
  <sql:param value="${empId}" />
</sql:update>

<sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result">
   SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Emp ID</th>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>Age</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
   <td><a href="?empId=[empId to remove]">Delete</a></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.empId}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Still getting error after updating with answer below. Anyone have any ideas???, could you please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think anchor tag has problem.  You are passing `[empId to remove]` instead of valid `empId`

Change

```
<a href="?empId=[empId to remove]">Delete</a>
                    ↑
```

To,

```
<a href="?empId=${row.empId}">Delete</a>
```

**From stacktrace**

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type
```

`[empId to remove]` is invalid SQL data type.

**Edit**

Things to look

1. You are submitting a form but there is no `submit button`
2. Anchor tag `<a href="?empId=[empId to remove]">Delete</a>` which is the action it will call?
3. You are printing form in loop

Create two `JSP` files, one to display all records with delete link `view_all.jsp` and second `reserve.jsp` as you mentioned in `form` tag.

**view_all.jsp**

```
<sql:setDataSource
  var = "bookdB"
  scope = "session"
  driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
  url = "jdbc:odbc:bookdB"
/>

<sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result">
   SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Emp ID</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
  <tr>
   <td><a href="reserve.jsp?empId=${row.empId}">Delete</a></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.empId}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
  </tr>
 </form>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

**reserve.jsp**

```
<sql:setDataSource
  var = "bookdB"
  scope = "session"
  driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
  url = "jdbc:odbc:bookdB"
/>

//get the empId send from view_all.jsp 
<c:set var="empId" value="${requestScope.empId}"/> 

<sql:update dataSource="${bookdB}" var="count">
  DELETE FROM Employees WHERE empId = ?
  <sql:param value="${empId}" />
</sql:update>
```

Comment: Getting the same error. Thanks for trying though. I think there's a problem with the line |<c:set var="empId" value="${param['empId']}"/>|.

Comment: @ConorCaslin : can you just print `empId`? `<c:set var="empId" value="${param['empId']}"/>` after this line type `<c:out value="${empId}"/>` have you referred [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_param_tag.htm)

Comment: I'm still getting the invalid SQl data type error if I leave in the line `<c:set var="empId" value="${param['empId']}"/>`. i can print the row number, without this line though, because the JSP file will complile then

Comment: the jsp file won't compile though

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. The row doesn't delete from the database though.

Comment: I used the two JSP Files, The initial view_all.jsp loads up, but when I select delete, I get the Invalid SQL data type error again, when it trys to load the reserve.jsp. Seems like theres no getting away from it. Any ideas???